# The User Profile Service

Tags: windows-7, windows, services

I tried logging into my computer after an "ungraceful" shutdown due to a power cut.. I got prompted with a message stating the user profile service failed the login.

After reading a k/b on Microsoft I managed to re-login to the "corrupt" account by making registery edits..

But the next step (After having the ability to logon) is a major concern for me.. Would the guys at superuser suggest:

> 1) Carry on using said account
>   2) Re-install Windows to eliminate the possible chance of a reoccouring problem
>
> 3) Migrate all user data
>   over to a new account

and with that being said above. I had to issue the command line:

```
net user administrator /active:yes
```

to activate the hidden adminstrator account, would it be recommended/secure to disable the account or leave it active?

Comment: Can you elaborate on "re-login to the 'corrupt' account by making registery edits" as if done correctly you shouldn't have further issues

Comment: @50-3 It feels like a dirty hack, I followed: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_vista-security/user-profile-service-service-failed-the-logon-user/4ed66b21-c23e-42f1-98b2-706dcf931fae

Comment: Rename the administrator folder in `c:\users\ ` to something else then login with the administrator account. you will have to do a lot of rebuilding but you will keep the `SID` so perms won't be an issue. I find with windows an Issue is only an issue if re-occurs and everything I do in windows makes me fell dirty that's half the fun :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you have access, backup your critical files.

Just create a new profile and copy over your files, etc. (choice 3.). Then delete the corrupted profile.

Disable the administrator account until you need it again.

Maybe run `SFC /SCANNOW` to check system integrity after you've copied everything over.